# define a duration variable as integer or numeric?

Tags: lme4-nlme

I have a question related to choice of integer or numeric. In my paper, I measure voice onset time (VOT), which is a durational property of speech sounds. It includes both negative and positive measurements. I have two questions. First, should I define VOT variable as integer or numeric? Second, if I do an anova (LMER) to test the effect of some variables on VOT, can I just run it without considering negative and positive numbers?

Comment: 1) Does it make a difference how you define it?

Comment: 2) Sure you _can_. Does it make theoretical sense? Not sure.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! 1) how would I Know if it makes a difference? should I compare the results in both cases? It may sound like a silly question but pardon me this is the first time I deal with statistics. 2) I just want to know if it doesn't affect the p values and give wrong results.

Comment: It might depend on the software that you are using, but try it both ways and see if you get the same answer. If you do get the same answer (and I suspect you will) then it doesn't matter.